# Python Gtk3 how to make a formatable textbox

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm trying to create a formatable text box in python gtk3, but when run, this just gets a segmentation fault. Does anyone know how to create and configure a textbox tag by line.char indexes?

```
Class window(gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.frame = gtk.VBox()
    self.add(self.frame)

    self.b = gtk.Button("Highlight")
    self.b.connect("clicked", lambda event: self.configure_text(0.0, 1.5, background="red"))

    self.frame.pack_start(self.b, False, True, 0)

    self.text = gtk.TextView()
    self.frame.pack_start(self.text, False, True, 0)

    self.textbuff = self.text.get_buffer()

    self.tags = []



    self.show_all()

  def configure_text(self, index1, index2, **args):

    index1_ = gtk.TextIter()
    index1_.set_line(int(float(index1)))

    index2_ = gtk.TextIter()
    index2_.set_line(int(float(index2)))

    tag = self.textbuff.create_tag("ping!", background="orange")
    self.textbuff.apply_tag(tag, index1_, index2_)

    self.tags.append(tag)
```

Comment: This is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In your code I at least see uninitialized `TextIter`s. Obtain it from `TextView` with `get_line_at_y`